# SQL lite and Postgre SQL both for rails production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql-9.1

In Rails production, I want to use SQL Lite as cache mechanism for storing data and Postgre for production database.Can we have both SQL Lite and Postgre in rails production at same time ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use memcached or redis instead of Sqlite?

Comment: Sqlite suits best for requirement and it's available out of box in rail server.Furthermore, I want in-memory cache rather running another server for cache. 
Can use sql queries to fetch custom data